# 'CKEditor 4.x is missing (http://ckeditor.com/)' warning in using ng2-ckeditor, angular 4

Tags: angular, components

I am going to use ng2-ckeditor plugin for my angular 4 project.
I read guide and there was configuration of systemjs file.
But I couldn't find systemjs in my angular 4 cli project.
So I did other things mentioned in guide except systemjs config.
And the last result was simple textbox and warning

```
'CKEditor 4.x is missing (http://ckeditor.com/)'
```

These are all I have done.

```
1)    /*added this script to my component html file*/
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
2) 
npm install ng2-ckeditor
3) set appmodule
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

@NgModule({
  // ... 
  imports:      [
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  // ... 
})
export class AppModule { }

4) use component
      <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="content" debounce="500">
      <p>Hello <strong>world</strong></p>
      </ckeditor>
```

I want to know how to set systemjs even I can't find systemjs file in my project
And is there anyway without setting this?
Best Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Import the script in your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. and I have one question more.
what is difference of inserting script in component's template html and inserting script in index.html?
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script> in samplecomponent.html


and <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script> in index.html

Comment: Script tags are not allowed in component templates. Including scripts in your index.html should make them globally accessible

Comment: Thanks. then, how to load custom javascript code in special component? If load script into index.html, site will load that script whether it needed or not.

Comment: With CKeditor there is a issue you can check that here [link](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/90). And if you want to import third party js in component check this link it has a dedicated question on it 
[ThirdpartyJS](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq)

Comment: Ok,I have one question more.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277131/why-use-apostrophe-for-varialbes-in-angular-4
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I am facing the same problem in my karma testing. while testing the compoenent, it says the same error. any suggestion?

Comment: same problem means

Comment: I have added the script to my html but still get error :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Error: CKEditor 4.x is missing (http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Please get the updated script form [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor)

Answer (score 1):

If still anyone faces the issue even after importing @RahulSingh given script, please use `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>`
[reference](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/105)

Comment: Please get the updated script form [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your DNS to Google public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

After it, you can go to your browser, paste your DNS address and verify if it's opening... if it is or not, try the same address with http instead https (for some reason, it only work after enter in http address.. maybe a coincidence, but better garantee).

Note: always keep your cdn with https address.

More informations: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using