# Why use apostrophe for variables in Angular 4

Tags: angular, directive

I want to know about the difference between these two lines.

```
<p [myHighlight]="'yellow'">Highlighted in yellow</p>
<p myHighlight="orange">Highlighted in orange</p>
```

`myHighlight` is custom directive where all tags inside it will be set custom color.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of [this page on the angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) it will tell you all about the template syntax.

But simply the top row will be evaluated as an expression and the line below as a constant.

Quoted from the docs.

> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If you
>   omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and
>   initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate
>   the string!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` in `[myHighlight]="'yellow'"` means that the part in `="..."` is an expression. Without `''` Angular wants to read the value from an identifier with the name `yellow`. If you want the literal value, instead of a reference, you need `''`, the same as you would need in TypeScript.

Without `''` Angular interprets the value as string literal, like it is usually done with attribute values in plain HTML+JS.